# Shell script not running through all files of certain extensions

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script that searches the directory that it is in for files that match any suffixes in the env var SUFFIXES.

```
#!/bin/bash

SUFFIXES=$(SUFFIXES:-'.c .cpp .cc'}
CC=${CC:-gcc}
CFLAGS=${CFLAGS:-"-Wall -Werror"}
VERBOSE=${VERBOSE:-1}

for i in *$SUFFIXES
do
    $CC $CLAGS -o ${i%$SUFFIXES} $i 2> /dev/null
    if [ $VERBOSE == 1 ]
    then
        echo "$CC $CLAGS -o ${i%$SUFFIXES} $i"
    fi
done
```

Say I have a directory with hello.c, hey.c, howdy.cc, and hallo.cpp. Whenever the script is ran without changing the environment variables in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o hello.c hello.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -o hey.c hey.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -o .cc .cc
gcc -Wall -Werror -o .cpp .cpp
```

The output that I am trying to get is:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o hello hello.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -o hey hey.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -o howdy howdy.cc
gcc -Wall -Werror -o hallo hallo.cpp
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You have syntax errors, probably introduced by copying the script as it won't run as it is

Answer (score 1):

Except for a few typos in your code that probably occurred here, you have some mistake in your loop

1. `i in *$SUFFIXES` means that `*.c .cpp .cc`, so it won't work on file.cpp or file .cc
2. `${i%$SUFFIXES}` try to cut all suffixes that you defined, from end of file name, while you have one of them in each file name

maybe an inner loop will helpful

```
for i in $SUFFIXES
do
    for j in *$i
    do                                                    
        $CC $CFLAGS -o ${j%$i} $j 2> /dev/null
        if [ $VERBOSE == 1 ]
        then
            echo "$CC $CFLAGS -o ${j%$i} $j"
        fi
    done
done
```